# Will process.send always succeed after callback is called?

Tags: node.js, child-process

In Node.js I have a `parent.js` script and a `child.js` script. What `parent.js` should do is to take care of its `child.js` so that whenever it doesn't exit gracefully it is supposed to do something to it and then restart it. However, `child.js` is actually supposed, sometimes, to exit gracefully. So I thought I could use `process.send` from `child.js` to just let `parent.js` know that it is dying but it is happy about it. I thought about stating it like this:

```
process.send('I am dying but it is okay.', function(error)
{
   if(!error)
      rest_in_peace();
});
```

Now, on [Child Process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_callback) it says that `callback()` could be called *before* the message has actually been delivered. Now, since I suppose that dying also means closing the connection with your parent process, is it safe to do something like that? Assuming that `parent.js` is completely failure proof and healthy, can I assume that, even if `callback` is called on `child.js` side before the message is delivered, `child.js` can happily shut down knowing that the message will be delivered at some time? Or should I figure out a way to do some kind of acknowledgement process between the two processes so that I actually get to know if the message was actually delivered?

Comment: Have you considered using exit codes to convey to the parent that a child has (or hasn't) exited gracefully? It depends on what you consider to be graceful, or not, but generally an exit code of 0 is considered "okay", and anything else isn't. See [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code).

Comment: Yes, I gave it a thought, but I am developing this thing as a library, and I would have preferred not using exit codes since I didn't want to force my users to use exit codes as I want them to.

Comment: Exit codes as a means to convey some status from child to parent seems to be more generally used (certainly in Unix-type OS'es) than custom messages being sent between them.